# How to use split, cast, case when all at same time for a single field in MS SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL Server and I have a column of type `varchar` with values in that column like this

```
2A, 10H, 4, 6T
```

I need output like this for above examples,

- 2A --> 2 + 0.25 (A = 0.25) --> **2.25**
- 1H --> 10 + 0.5 (H = 0.5) --> **10.5**
- 4 --> **4**
- 6T --> 6 + 0.75 (T = 0.75) --> **6.75**

I know that I have to split it into two parts and then use cast and case-when somehow and then sum it, but couldn't achieve it.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Show us what you have tried and what is not working.  And what is your logic for doing the replacements?  Your example is completely arbitrary.

Comment: `A = 0.25`, `H = 0.5`, `T = 0.75` Why? Where does this information come from? Why are you not using "normal" numerical values?

Comment: Can a value have multiple letters too? Would `'3AA'` be equal to `2.5` or `'17AH'` be equal to `17.75`?

Comment: @Larnu thank you for your help, 1) I can't control input because it's 3rd party data we are getting so I have to handle it 2) no there are no possibilities with 3AA or 17AH, it will be always single char at last from any of three

Answer (score 1):

*Assuming* the values are always an integer followed by a number, then you could just use `REPLACE`. I use a `JOIN` to a `VALUES` table construct here as you could easily replace it with an actual table to be scalable:

```sql
SELECT TRY_CONVERT(decimal(12,2),CONCAT(LEFT(YT.YourColumn,PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',YT.YourColumn+ '.')-1),V.NumericalValue))
FROM (VALUES('2A'),('10H'),('4'),('6T'))YT(YourColumn)
     LEFT JOIN (VALUES('A','0.25'),('H','0.5'),('T','0.75'))V(Character, NumericalValue) ON YT.YourColumn LIKE '%' + V.Character;
```

Comment: thank you for your response, but I think you are considering 2A, 10H are fixed values but actually it's one column from a table, any help?

Comment: I don't follow your comment, @VishalZanzrukia . You said yourself that the only characters could be `A`, `H`, and `T` as I ***EXPLICITLY*** [asked you this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69618034/how-to-use-split-cast-case-when-all-at-same-time-for-a-single-field-in-ms-sql/69618609?noredirect=1#comment123053552_69618034). Are you now saying there are other letters? If so, you should have included that in your question... Though the solution is the same, just add the others to the `VALUES` value expression aliased as `V`.

Comment: both are different thing, A, H, T are only chars we have but I can see you have also considered 2, 10, 4 & 6 are fixed values, that is difference, I have a table column that can have any number of rows with values like 2A, 10H, 4, 12A, 8H, 5, 5T, 6T etc

Comment: Because those are the examples you gave, @VishalZanzrukia ... Why would i use different values? You would obviously be using your table. There's a reason  the column is aliased as `YourColumn`; because it would be **Your Column**...

Comment: ok, got it, will try, but with the existing query I am getting this  `ERROR: syntax error at or near "," Position: 33` any help about this?

Comment: The above works fine for me, @VishalZanzrukia [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7e0fbf8d7503efb8339a7a768b79aa64). If it's not for you, you've changed it in some way.

Comment: Wait... That doesn't look like a SQL Server error, @VishalZanzrukia .

Comment: you are right, was running in the wrong window but now I am running it in MS SQL Server 2017 (using DBeaver client) and now getting this `SQL Error [195] [50010]: 'decimal' is not a recognized built-in function name.`

Comment: Again, sounds like you've changed something,. @VishalZanzrukia .

Comment: here is the screenshot with query and error both, it's exact your query, https://prnt.sc/1wpm3ji

Comment: Use a fiddle to replicate the problem, as I demosntrated, the above work, @VishalZanzrukia . Images of code don't help.